# Leisure and Entertainment

Tags: connect-wall

An only connect wall. Or is it?

[image]

Here is a text version of the table:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Music | Chamber | Clay | Saturn |
| Castle | Tree | Snow | Stone |
| Trip | Candle | Engagement | Havoc |
| Ashes | Tower of Hanoi | Surprise | Small |

Comment: Long time no see :-)!

Comment: Nice to see you, too. :) I did throw a peek every now and then... :)

Comment: Welcome back! :D

Comment: chamber and havoc are both from xmen if that helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Continuing Matt's answer, the other two groups can be:

Group 3:

> **The Hobbit**
>  Small
>  Surprise
>  Trip (The first three literally reads as *The Hobbit: An unexpected journey*)
>  Havoc (For *The Battle of the Five Armies*)

Group 4:

> **Game of Thrones**
>  Music
>  Snow
>  Candle (The first three literally reads as *A Song of Ice and Fire*)
>  Castle (For the "thrones" in *Game of Thrones*)

The bigger connection between the four group is that

> They are great **fantasy epos**es, with multiple books each (I guess thats why it's is not "*an only connect wall*")

Comment: That's correct :)

Answer (score 8):

**Work in Progress**

Group 1

> **Lord of the Rings**
>  Saturn
>  Engagement
>  Tower of Hanoi
>  Tree (rings for age)

Group 2

> **Harry Potter**
>  Chamber
>  Clay
>  Ashes (urn)
>  Stone (stoner)

Comment: Group 1 is correct.

Comment: "Harry Potter" group could also be **Chamber** (of secrets), (Sorcerer's) **Stone**, **Castle** (Hogwarts), **Ashes** (phoenix)

Comment: @tmpearce the Harry Potter group is correct. The Castle goes into another group. Otherwise your other associations are valid.

Answer (score 3):

Things you might shout

> "SNOW!", "HAVOC!", "road TRIP!", "SURPRISE!"

Pot-related Things

> Chamber, Clay, Ash, Tree (/r/tree)

Rings

> Saturn, Engagement, Towers of Hanoi, Stone

A good-seeming date that ends badly?

> Castle, Music, Candle, Small

Comment: Interestingly, all  your groups are on the verge of being correct, with only one mistake in each group.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Matt's answer, since he's got two groups right. I don't have enough rep to post a comment.

**Group 3**

> **Beauty and The Beast**
>  Small
>  Castle
>  Candle
>  Music

**Group 4**

> **Game of Thrones**
>  Trip
>  Snow
>  Havoc
>  Surprise

Comment: Since a lot of movies/books may have similar things in their story line, the words do not point to the story line - just the title.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I can only find one group that makes any sense to me: (this is incorrect)</s>

> Tree, stone, snow, and clay.

They're all

> things naturally found in the world.

Another group:

> Music, candle, surprise, havoc - things that happen at a party

Comment: What about ashes

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil That's created by fire. The ones in my answer happen *without* a fire or anything.

Comment: These are not in the same group. :)